# Java Spring Autowiring with profile

Tags: java, spring

I have a class lets say class **A** which is a Configuration class and runs only when profile "production" is activated. But in class **B** where the main logic of the application is I am using @Autowired annotation that refers to some bean that is created in class **A**, my problem is when for example I run the application with profile lets say "default" it throws exception because the appropiate bean is not created. So my question is how I can use this Autowired in my class B only when profile "production" is active ?

Comment: Depending on your use-case, just create an interface that 2 classes implement. One is the real class, the other is a no-op class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing you have two implementations of A interface:

```
public interface A {}

@Component(value="A_dev")
public class ADev implements A {}

@Component(value="A_prod")
public class AProd implements A {}

public class B {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("A") A a;
}
```

Add an XML config with alias and a property placeholder:

```
<beans>
    <alias name="${a.class}" alias="A"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="app.properties"/>
<beans>
```

app.properties should contain

```
a.class=A_dev
```

Then changing propertiy will change your injected class (app restart would be required).

There are other solutions such as:

- Filtering XML context with maven (build time)
- Creating a bean factory which returns different A implementations depending on something
- Using spring EL #{expression}

Answer (score 14):

I didn't understand your question. but if you need to inject optional beans ,you can use `@Autowired(required = false)`  then in a environment which doesn't have any qualifying bean the relevant property will be null.